# Using tidyverse in R how do I arrange my column values in a fixed way?

Tags: r

```
ID score
a  1
a  2
b  2
b  4
c  4
c  5
```

I want to change id to "a,b,c" order this to

```
ID score
a  1
b  2
c  4
a  2
b  4
c  5
```

What I tried

```
> data <- read_csv(data)
> data <- factor(data$id, levels = c('a', 'b', 'c'))
```

This works for tables so I tried it but didn't work for this. Anybody know if there is a way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of assigning the 'id' column to `data <-` (which would replace the data with the 'id' values) it would be used for `order`ing.  In `base R`, this can be done with

```
data1 <-  data[order(duplicated(data$ID)),]
row.name(data1) <- NULL
```

Or with `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
library(data.table)
data %>%
     arrange(rowid(ID))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
library(dplyr)
d %>%
    group_by(ID) %>%
    mutate(r = row_number()) %>%
    ungroup() %>%
    arrange(r, ID, score) %>%
    select(-r)
```

OR in base R

```
with(d, d[order(ave(seq(NROW(d)), d$ID, FUN = seq_along), ID, score),])
```